# PHP Google Maps Geocoding XML load issue

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, geocoding

This is really weird and has me baffled. I have a PHP script that collects data from an address input form, formats it for the googlemaps geocoding service, and then loads the xml this service returns and extracts the lat/lng out of it. What's weird is that certain addresses return the "url not loading" die message, but when I copy the exact string that is echod out that the script is sending and paste it into my browser, i do in fact get the xml file. Anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Here is the string that is echo'd out. Maybe someone can tell me what PHP doesn't like about this URL?

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=ABQIAAAAZe-W-lkccZSM2qC_Ci4JnBS97eShVNVCdPw2dK9jd_Ls-9Sg7hSJTMXMmezqrmN9bDDbO_CSRwChtw&q=285+East+Grand+Avenue,+Fox Lake,+IL,+60020&sensor=true_or_false

Here is the script:

```
//This section sends HTTP geocode to google and recieves the XML
$googlekey = "ABQIAAAAZe-W-lkccZSM2qC_Ci4JnBS97eShVNVCdPw2dK9jd_Ls-9Sg7hSJTMXMmezqrmN9bDDbO_CSRwChtw";
$mapAddress = urlencode($barAddress).",+".$barCity.",+".$barState.",+".$barZip;
echo $mapAddress."<br />";
$googleURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=".$googlekey."&q=".$mapAddress."&sensor=true_or_false";
echo $googleURL."<br />";
$googlexml = simplexml_load_file($googleURL) or die("url not loading<br />");
$status = $googlexml - > Response - > Status - > code;
if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
    echo "barID:".$barID;
    // Successful geocode
    $coordinates = $googlexml - > Response - > Placemark - > Point - > coordinates;
    $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
    // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
    $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
    $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];
    echo "lat:".$lat." lon:".$lng;
    $xmlUpdate = "/".$barID."/".$barID.".xml";

    //This is the final query that updates
    $updateQuery = sprintf("UPDATE userBars "." SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s', barXML = '%s' "."  WHERE barID = '%s';", mysql_real_escape_string($lat), mysql_real_escape_string($lng), mysql_real_escape_string($xmlUpdate), mysql_real_escape_string($barID));
    $updateResult = mysql_query($updateQuery);

    if ($updateResult) {
        echo "Successfully Geocoded!<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Geocode Not Successful!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Geocode Failed.";
}
}
} else {
    echo "Error retrieving barID. Files and entries were not created successfully.<br />";
}
```

Comment: Doh! Posting that link into this forum just made me realize that its because i wasn't urlencoding the city, and any city with seperate names was throwing it off. Solved!

Comment: Just a side note: scraping coordinates with a shell-script works without the google-key.